Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder
I have a question about adding components to a DI container, but doing so in such a way that once added, they retain the data they have been populated with. Is this even possible?  I am beginning to think not as I have found nothing that addresses this question. If it is possible, I will update this post with some code to get better direction.
I had a handful of static classes that I populated with data during my startup procedures from an AppSettings.json file. The data is fixed and never changes, and since I am now setting up a Hosting environment I was curious as to whether or not this is possible.
Thanks in advance.

I found the answer to my question here on Stack Overflow once I found the right search terms. The short answer is yes, you can add a component that has already been instantiated with data to the DI container. However, there are some caveats to consider.

The componet must be created, have it's data added then added to the Service Collection before the DI container is built. Once the Service Collection is built it is read only.

This constructor must be used when adding to the Service Collection:
ServiceCollection.AddKeyedSingleton[TService](object ServiceKey, object myComponentInstance);

When the Singlketon instance is pulled from the DI container and used, it is NOT automatically disposed of and remains in the DI container until an explict Dispose is called on that instance or the application as a whole is exited.


There are additional details in the answer as described in this Stack Overflow question: AddSingleton<>() vs AddSingleton()
